# How to add random colors to world map using jvectormap?Error map not loaded

Tags: javascript, jsp, jvectormap

I want to use the random coloring example to color a worldmap. I am using jvectormap for the map.
The map doesnt render for me. I get a javascript error - attempt to use a map not loaded 'world-mill-en'. I am able to render the map when I just use the function

`$(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap();
    });`

But it doesnt work with the code below. Please advise, this is a critical project for me.thanks in advance.

```
&copy;<html><head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/charts.css">
<title>Maps</title></head><div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
&copy;<script type="text/javascript">
map = new jvm.WorldMap({
    map: 'world-mill-en',
    container: $('#world-map'),
    series: {
        regions: [{
            attribute: 'fill'
        }]
    }
});
$(function(){
    var palette = ['#66C2A5', '#FC8D62', '#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854'];
    generateColors = function(){
        var colors = {},key;

        for (key in map.regions) {
            colors[key] = palette[Math.floor(Math.random()*palette.length)];
        }
        return colors;
    }, map;

    map.series.regions[0].setValues(generateColors());
})
```

Comment: Have you found a solution in the end? anybody?!

Comment: i worked out the problem myself. will share the fix tonite